# How to unit 2 or more Data Series in group by One Chart C#

Tags: c#

Develop a chart in C #, this is filled automatically with a sp. The sp spreads cities with totals that month are filtered, as I show in the image.

[image]

Within my Chart, I add 2 sets of data although they may be more in the future. The problem is not to add the series of data, but how to respect the order of the data, if I add the series of data as secondary, it does perfectly, but I do not group them but transpose them and I do not respect the Order of the same.

[image]

I would like to know if any of you know how to do this, I have already verified on the internet and I can not find information. I add the sp who throw me the information, I also throw them as I group the data in the chart and as I would like to be grouped regardless of whether in the following month there would be more cities.

This code add data series to chart

```
conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("sp_telemetria_camiones_Km_Mes_Actual");    
            conexion_server.AgregarParametro("Mes", SqlDbType.VarChar, strmes);    
            mes_actual = conexion_server.EjecutaComandoDataSet();                  
            graf_km_camiones_comparativo.Titles.Add("Comparativa KMS entre Camiones \\n" + strmes + " VS " + strmes_comparativo).Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            graf_km_camiones_comparativo.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            graf_km_camiones_comparativo.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            graf_km_camiones_comparativo.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "(#VALX, #VALY)";
            graf_km_camiones_comparativo.Series["Series2"].ToolTip = "(#VALX, #VALY)";    
            graf_km_camiones_comparativo.Series["Series1"].LegendText = strmes;
            graf_km_camiones_comparativo.Series["Series2"].LegendText = strmes_comparativo;    
            graf_km_camiones_comparativo.Legends["Legend1"].Title = "Segmentación";      
            foreach (DataRow row in mes_actual.Tables[0].Rows)
            {    
                graf_km_camiones_comparativo.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(row["CeEmplazamiento"], row["Totales"]);

                graf_km_camiones_comparativo.Series["Series1"].Label = "#VALY";    
            }


Thank you.
```

Comment: Since your x-values are string it is up to you to make sure any 'CeEmplazamiento' gets a datapoint on each series! your two SPs are obviously not doing this. you need some outer join, as far as I remember..

Comment: It is something in which I thought, to extract the data and then to make a join so that those equal values group them and those that do not appear, add them to me as empty.

Comment: Yes, that is one way; usually doing it all on the DBMS side is more elgant. Make sure all data stay ordered the way you want..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for your comments, this was my solution. 
1.- To créate a unión between the queries, because isn't posible to organize the series without a query.
2.- The Chart  was fill with a foreach.

e

```
,final_comparativo as (
                    select s.CeEmplazamiento, avg(s.Totales) TotalGeneral , s2.TotGral, @Mes as Mes
                    from tmpSemanas s
                        cross join ( select avg(Totales) TotGral from tmpSemanas s2 where Totales >0) s2
                    group by s.CeEmplazamiento , s2.TotGral
            union all
                    select ss.CeEmplazamiento, avg(ss.Totales) TotalGeneral , ss2.TotGral, @Mes_comparar as Mes
                    from tmpSemanas_comparar ss
                        cross join ( select avg(Totales) TotGral from tmpSemanas_comparar ss2 where Totales >0) ss2
                    group by ss.CeEmplazamiento , ss2.TotGral
        )   


**CeEmplazamiento   Diciembre   Enero**
Celaya          76.500000   75.600000
Coecillo            79.000000   79.800000
Irapuato            77.500000   75.400000
León Sur            85.750000   87.600000
Los Reyes            0.000000   0.000000
Oriente León    86.250000   85.200000
Texcoco          0.000000   0.000000
```

[image]
Thanks to everybody